# how to get Ubuntu to load via DVD onto pc on xp

Tags: boot, 14.04, system-installation, dvd, 32-bit

Downloaded the 32bit Desktop 14.04 version using a Windows 7 laptop.  I have checked the download using winMD5SUM - ok- and burned a DVD using Deepburner.

After several tries at booting the pc in which I set it to boot from DVD via <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F11</kbd>, the screen showed the deep red Ubuntu screen with 2 small white images at the bottom then the screen quickly went blank with a message window from the maker in a far eastern alphabet which includes an exclamation mark in a triangle.
Have tried several times and on one occasion I accidentally pressed <kbd>F2</kbd> later, the language choice list in Ubuntu came up and a page where I chose 'try without installing'. It quickly reverted to the blank screen with the screen image with exclamation mark as above.

Comment: Are you trying to install a [tag:dual-boot] system?  Also, did you verify that your Windows 7 machine was running 32-bit (right-click Computer for properties)?

Comment: No, I thought not dual boot as cannot use xp online safely now. Yes I think 32-bit,  in Display Properties it shows Colour quality: highest (32-bit).  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I mis-read you, the Windows 7 laptop is 64-bit but I'm trying to install Ubuntu on the old xp PC.  On this I can't find how to find the same info, only  'colour quality 32-bit'.

Comment: The 'old' XP PC, if you can still boot from it, visit this page for an example of system properties http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windowsxp/ht/windows-xp-32-bit-64-bit.htm

Comment: Running XP Home Edition 2002 so it must be 32-bit then, thanks.

Comment: @user277569 the dvd may not have burned properly. You may wish to double check that the md5sum matches the 32 bit version. Also check to see if the disk will autorun in your windows 7 system